# How can I change the order in which disks appear in the command "wmic diskdrive get"

Tags: windows, windows-11, wmic, disk-drive

How can I change the order in which disks appear in the command `wmic diskdrive get`?

`wmic diskdrive get` output

[image: wmic diskdrive get]

I want to move the Samsung SSD 980 PRO 2TB to the first position.

Comment: You can't. What are you actually trying to achieve? This question seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how wmic diskdrive does the sorting of disk drives. I know there are other simpler ways to achieve this goal of sorting the drive information.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the powershell command instead of the WMIC command which is deprecated.

The equivalent command is the following :

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object -Property Model,SerialNumber
```

Now you can change the order by sorting the output. You have to pipe the result to the `Sort-Object` command.

For example, you can sort on Model :

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object -Property Model,SerialNumber | Sort-Object Model
```

Comment: Power shell is indeed much easier to use than wmic to some extent, But I'm more interested in understanding how wmic sorts the drives. Thank you for your great answer!